# How can I restart the services that power Sidecar on my MacBook?

Tags: launchd, sidecar

When I try to connect my MacBook Pro (2023, M2, running macOS 13.2) to my iPad Pro (running iPadOS 16.1.1) using Sidecar via Control Center, the little screen icon turns blue without ever showing a loading spinner, and Sidecar never connects. I'm trying to avoid restarting my MacBook right this second so I'm trying to find out if there's a process I can kill/restart in order to get it out of its currently funky state.

This started happening a couple of days ago over a wireless connection only (wired still worked), but now wired also doesn't work. I've tried issuing a kill signal to a few processes listed [here](https://gist.github.com/dmattera/883a4457b67534df795cdd0fa1651a26), but it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

`$ launchctl list | grep com.apple.sidecar` returns the following:

```
96786   -9  com.apple.sidecar-relay
21111   -9  com.apple.sidecar-display-agent
```

So I tried killing them:

```
sudo launchctl kill KILL gui/501/com.apple.sidecar-display-agent
sudo launchctl kill KILL gui/501/com.apple.sidecar-relay
```

Now the "Screen Mirroring" Control Center only shows the heading and "Display Settings...", so I'm trying to figure out how to restart it. I tried the following:

```
$ sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.sidecar-relay.plist
Warning: Expecting a LaunchDaemons path since the command was ran as root. Got LaunchAgents instead.
`launchctl bootstrap` is a recommended alternative.

$ sudo launchctl bootstrap /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.sidecar-relay.plist
Unrecognized target specifier.
```